# WPF Window does not finish rendering when download starts

Tags: wpf, doevents

I am writing a small file download utility. The **DownloadFile()** method is called on **Window_Loaded()** event of my *MainWindow*. Since the **DownloadFile** method is resource intensive, the *MainWindow* does not finish rendering on screen when the download starts. It is just after the download is finished that I come to see the actual controls on my WPF Form.

To control this, I am using following **DoEvents()** code, but still it is not working. I am calling this function after **InitializeComponent()** in the Form constructor and just before calling **DownloadFile()** in the **Window_Loaded** event.

```
private void DoEvents()
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                                                  new Action(delegate { }));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is always suggested to do all the server hits and download related things in a separate thread. You can see how to that in following link.

http://bathinenivenkatesh.blogspot.com/2011/07/wpf-build-more-responsive-ui.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [DownloadFileAsync method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms144196%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should use BeginInvoke instead (with the Background option) and put the DownloadFile there.

Comment: I am using a third-party tool. It does have FileAsync method, but still the same problem.